# install cisco VPN client on linux in place on WIN XP

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco

I have win XP with VPN client version - Cisco 5.0.01.0600

Now we want to replace the WIN XP with linux machine , red-hat version 5.x or 6.x ,

My question is , what the equivalent VPN version that I need to install on the new Linux machine , ( in order to get full compatibility as it was on the WIN xp machine )

Please advice also where I can download the cisco VPN version for linux